# Laravel Middleware Class 'App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth' not found

Tags: laravel, middleware

So I'm trying to use middleware to authenticate users on a few pages of my application, but I'm getting this error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth' not found
```

Here's CheckAuth.php:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth as Middleware;

class CheckAuth extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->auth > 0) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and here's Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'authenticated' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth::class
];
```

When I try to use the middleware (like this `->middleware('authenticated');`) I get the error.

Thanks.

Comment: you're declaring a class that extends itself ? class CheckAuth extends Middleware

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;


class CheckAuth 
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->auth > 0) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Always explain your answers. Just a piece of code will solve the problem, but not teach about it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `use App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth as Middleware;` you're in the same Class File. you don't need to use it again.

Remove this line from the top of middleware.

```
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth as Middleware;
```

And you don't need to extends that Middleware as well

Now, your code looks like below.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class CheckAuth 
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->auth > 0) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Use command to create middleware

```
 php artisan make:middleware CheckAuth
```